# How would I remove "<function main at 0x7f2dba025d30>

Tags: python, syntax, yfinance

How do I properly fix the main function? How would I remove "<function main at 0x7f2dba025d30>" from my output? My output works fine but I get

The following output:

```
function main at 0x7f2dba025d30>
AAPL 155.09
MSFT 287.15
AMD 109.33
```

```
import yfinance as yf

stocks = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'AMD']

def main():
    for stock in stocks:
        info = yf.Ticker(stock).info
        marketprice = info.get('regularMarketPrice')
        print(stock, marketprice)
print(main)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: If you don't want to print that, why do you print that?

Comment: you are telling it to print that, so just remove `print(main)`?

Comment: `main()` doesn't even return anything, so even if you called it and printed its output, like `print(main())`, you'd just end up printing `None` since a function that doesn't return anything implicitly returns `None`. Your `main()` function already prints things, so there's no need to do any extra `print`s in the first place. Also, the reason it has that output is because you're not even calling `main`, you're passing the function _itself_ to `print()`.

Answer (score 1):

You are outputting `<function main at 0x7f2dba025d30>` because of the following line:

```py
print(main)
```

This essentially tells Python to display the object `main` which is indeed, a function.

Removing the line will remove the output.